# Dynamically Allocated Memory and Structures Access in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, dynamic, allocation

I am trying to loop through a dynamically allocated memory array, in order to access it, and input elements in each or the array items. The elements type are in a structure. My concept was to loop through the array first, then access the structure elements so I can input data for each array element. I do not know how to do it. This is the code I have so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

//Declaring Global constants



//structures
struct carInfo
{
    string makeAndModel = "NONE";
    int modelYear = 0;
    double Mileage = 0;

};





//Function Prototypes
void displayTitle();
void dataInput(int, int[]);




int main()
{
    //DEclare variables
    int numOfCarsOwned = 0;
    int* carNumberCount = nullptr;  //TO dynamically allocate an array to hold the number of cars the user has

    
    //CAll a funtion to Display Title

    displayTitle();

    //Ask the user for the number of cars they own

    cout << "Please enter the number of cars you own: ";
    cin >> numOfCarsOwned;

    while (numOfCarsOwned < 0)
    {
        cout << " Error - please enter a positive number! \n";
        cout << "Please enter the number of cars you own: ";
        cin >> numOfCarsOwned;
    }

    //Dynamically allocate an array to hold the number of cars

    carNumberCount = new int[numOfCarsOwned]; 

    //Send Array and Number of cars to a function to perform Data Input 

    dataInput(numOfCarsOwned, carNumberCount);











    system("pause");
    return 0;

}


//Function to display the title
void displayTitle()
{
    
}

//Function to collect Data Inputs
void dataInput( int numOfCarsOwned, int carNumberCount[])
{
    
    int count;
     
    //to loop through the carNumberCount and Put Data from the car info structure into each.
    for (count = 0; count < numOfCarsOwned; count++)
    {
        carInfo carNumberCount;


    }



}
```

Comment: What storage do you put `carInfo` into?  It seems need to redsign the func`dataInput` api.

Comment: whats your approach to change it?

Comment: You are creating array of integers with size of the input.
instead of `carNumberCount = new int[numOfCarsOwned]; ` you should create array of  `carInfo` to save info about cars like: `carNumberCount = new int[numOfCarsOwned];` then pass is to the function loop through elements and fill the data

Comment: i have tried to substitute the int data type to be of datatype carInfo, but the code does not compile anymore.